# Specify Columns in formula with xlsxwriter write_formula

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

i try to write some formulas into a excel table, but i dont like to specify the Cells by A1 , B2 etc. I´m searching for like one hour now - so i hope someone can help me :)

So far i can specify the Cell where the formula should be with row and column - but not the actual parameters (see code: B2-B3)

```py
def test():
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(...)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(name)
worksheet.write_formula(10, 0, '=ABS(B2-B3)')
```

Does anyone have a clue ?

---

Solution for the ABS formula:

```py
def writeAbsFormula(self, row, column, worksheet):
        formula = '=ABS(' + self.getCellFormat(row-2, column) + '-' + self.getCellFormat(row-1, column) + ')'
        worksheet.write_formula(row,column, formula)

def getCellFormat(self, row, column):
        cell = xlsxwriter.utility.xl_col_to_name(column)
        cell += str(row+1)
        return cell
```

Comment: I actually found a way to solve this using this function: xlsxwriter.utility.xl_col_to_name(column)